# Why doesn't TFS download subfolders if they are mapped elsewhere

Tags: tfs, version-control

I have a few environments setup that connect to TFS through an eclipse based IDE. I have the main project folder mapped to a local folder and I have 2 subfolders mapped to a different place locally. For some reason on only one of the environments when I perform a get operation, the subfolders that have been mapped additionally are not downloaded on both the main project folder and the external mappings.

I have tried recreating the workspace, removing the mapping, to re-install TFS 2012
What could be the possible culprit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have no business with subfolders if they are mapped elsewhere. You just make sure to perform a get operation at one or more level up of that subfolders.

In you case, you could first check the mappings for main project folder and 2 subfolders. Make sure they are **in a same workspace**.

Then try to get root folder in that workspace, check if this work.

Also try to [clear TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) in your dev machine, which may do trick.

If all of above still not work, suggest you use [get command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-command?view=azure-devops) line to download the folders, add `/recursive` such as `tf get $/Project/Main/recursive`

> Recursively gets items in the specified directory and any
>   subdirectories.

Comment: I will try that. The folders are in the same workspace, but one of the subfolders needs to reside outside of the parent one locally. The issue is that if it's mapped like this, a get operation on the main root folder doesn't get the subfolders that have their own mapping.

Comment: @floorpan I have created a simply test based on your structure could not reproduce your issue, it works properly. Just make sure the mappings and work folders are correctly. Please kindly try above solution, any result feel free to update here.

Comment: nope, we are discussing to move the whole project to git. We can't reproduce the issue anywhere else as well.